# react redux set ownProps from the component receiving ownProps

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I need to set the height of the ownProps from within the component that has the ownProps. It doesn't seem to update, it is always undefined.

Can it be done?

Here is my code, with the line of code to look at being commented with //////////////////

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: State, ownProps): Object => ({
  searchText: state.product.search.query.locationAutocomplete.searchText,
  place: state.product.search.query.locationAutocomplete.place,
  searchResults: state.product.search.query.locationAutocomplete.searchResults,
  shouldHideResults:
    state.product.search.query.locationAutocomplete.shouldHideResults,
  height: ownProps.height,
  onContentSizeChange: ownProps.onContentSizeChange
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<*>): Object => ({
  updateSearchQueryPageLocationAutocompleteSearchText: (searchText: string) => {
    dispatch(
      updateSearchQueryPageLocationAutocompleteSearchText({
        searchText: searchText
      })
    )
  },
  updateSearchQueryPageLocationAutocompletePlace: (locationPlace: Place) => {
    dispatch(
      updateSearchQueryPageLocationAutocompletePlace({
        locationPlace: locationPlace
      })
    )
  },
  getSearchQueryPageLocationAutocompletePlaceDetails: (placeId: number) => {
    dispatch(
      getSearchQueryPageLocationAutocompletePlaceDetails({ placeId: placeId })
    )
  },
  getSearchQueryPageLocationAutocompleteResults: (text: string) => {
    dispatch(getSearchQueryPageLocationAutocompleteResults({ text: text }))
  },
  updateProductSearchQueryPageIsLoctionListDisplayed: (displayed: boolean) => {
    dispatch(updateProductSearchQueryPageIsLoctionListDisplayed(displayed))
  },
  updateLocationShouldHideResults: (shouldHideResults: boolean) => {
    dispatch(updateSearchQueryPageShouldHideLocationResults(shouldHideResults))
  }
})

let LocationView = (props: LocationViewProps): Object => {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      value={props.searchText}
      customStyle={autocompleteStyle.customStyle(props.place)}
      placeholder={'Location'}
      updateValue={props.updateSearchQueryPageLocationAutocompleteSearchText}
      updateDataBehindValue={
        props.updateSearchQueryPageLocationAutocompletePlace
      }
      getDataBehindValueDetails={
        props.getSearchQueryPageLocationAutocompletePlaceDetails
      }
      autocompleteResults={props.searchResults}
      getSearchQueryPageLocationAutocompleteResults={
        props.getSearchQueryPageLocationAutocompleteResults
      }
      shouldHideResults={props.shouldHideResults}
      onListItemSelect={location => {
        props.getSearchQueryPageLocationAutocompletePlaceDetails(
          location.place_id
        )
        props.updateSearchQueryPageLocationAutocompleteSearchText(
          location.description
        )
        props.updateLocationShouldHideResults(true)
        props.updateProductSearchQueryPageIsLoctionListDisplayed(false)
      }}
      onContentSizeChange={height => {
        console.log(height)
        props.height = getHeight(height)}////////////////////////this line///////////////////////
      }
      onChangeText={text => onChangeText(props, text)}
    />
  )
}

const getHeight = height => {
  const h = Math.max(60, height)
  return h
}

LocationView = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(LocationView)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
height: ownProps.height,
```

It's unseless, either you receive your props from the parent `<MyComponent height={...} ...`, either you pass the props from your store `mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({ height: state..., //here ownProps contains to the props passed to MyComponent, so height={...} })`

If you want to change the props passed from the parent, use a handle function like that

```
handleSetheight = height => this.setState({ height }) 
return (<Child height={this.state.height} setHeight={this.handleSetHeight}/>)
```